# select font for tab headers in gvim

Tags: gvim, tabbed-user-interface, font

I wonder whether there is a way in gvim to select the font used for buffer names in tab headings (after using `:tabnew`). I know the guifont option, but this applies to the buffer editing area.

Ideally, I would like to choose the font family and size.

Comment: Please, specify your OS.

Comment: I’m not sure this is possible, but I could be wrong